# getting some error when using nuxeo-csv

Tags: csv, nuxeo

I'm using nuxeo-csv to import some documents with metadata, when clicking on "process button" i get this warning "An empty response was received from the server. Check server error logs." and some exceptions are generated in my log file, also i've to log out and log in in order to see the file imported. Any suggestion for how can I solve this ?

Comment: Please don't cross-post with Nuxeo Answers (https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/ae18e08581624ff6ac448b7d52a7ab29/nuxeo-csv-javax-servlet-ServletException)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Nuxeo 7.4 ([NXP-17360](https://jira.nuxeo.com/browse/NXP-17360))